# Files shown in Texshop dock icon

Tags: mac, texshop

When I double tap the Texshop dock icon on Mac (Big Sur), console and tex windows are shown. Usually I have a bunch of different tex files opened and console windows come first, possibly, because they are more recent documents.

Since I am more interested in opening tex windows than console windows, is it possible to remove the console windows from showing in the dock icon ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are talking about. Do you mean the list of recent documents?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the question.

Comment: First, do you mean windows or icons?And the Dock icon? Is there a reason you want the console icons at all? If not why not clean the aux files using `File->Trash Aux Files` for each source file once you don't need it any more?

Comment: You need to only single click the TeXShop doc icon to open TeXShop. By default macOS tells TeXShop opens all previously open documents/windows. This is an operation controlled by the OS. You completely turn it off in the General Pane of System Preferences.